# how do i add pitch_bend changes to function piano_roll_to_pretty_midi for produced music?

Tags: python

i want to use from function piano_roll_to_pretty_midi for convert properties music  but i don't know how add pitch_bend changes to this function, this is cod piano_roll:

```
def piano_roll_to_pretty_midi(piano_roll, fs=100, program=0):
    '''Convert a Piano Roll array into a PrettyMidi object
     with a single instrument.

    Parameters
    ----------
    piano_roll : np.ndarray, shape=(128,frames), dtype=int
        Piano roll of one instrument
    fs : int
        Sampling frequency of the columns, i.e. each column is spaced apart
        by ``1./fs`` seconds.
    program : int
        The program number of the instrument.

    Returns
    -------
    midi_object : pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI
        A pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI class instance describing
        the piano roll.

    '''
    notes, frames = piano_roll.shape
    pm = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI()
    instrument = pretty_midi.Instrument(program=program)

    # pad 1 column of zeros so we can acknowledge inital and ending events
    piano_roll = np.pad(piano_roll, [(0, 0), (1, 1)], 'constant')

    # use changes in velocities to find note on / note off events
    velocity_changes = np.nonzero(np.diff(piano_roll).T)

    # keep track on velocities and note on times
    prev_velocities = np.zeros(notes, dtype=int)
    note_on_time = np.zeros(notes)

    for time, note in zip(*velocity_changes):
        # use time + 1 because of padding above
        velocity = piano_roll[note, time + 1]
        time = time / fs
        if velocity > 0:
            if prev_velocities[note] == 0:
                note_on_time[note] = time
                prev_velocities[note] = velocity
        else:
            pm_note = pretty_midi.Note(
                velocity=prev_velocities[note],
                pitch=note,
                start=note_on_time[note],
                end=time)
            instrument.notes.append(pm_note)
            prev_velocities[note] = 0
    pm.instruments.append(instrument)
    return pm
```

Comment: You're using the [pretty_midi](https://pypi.org/project/pretty_midi/) library, right?

Comment: yes exactly i use of pretty_midi for generate music

Answer (score 0):

You add `PitchBend` objects to the instrument's `pitch_bends`
list. Here is a MWE that adds notes from a piano roll and also bends
them:

```
from pretty_midi import *
from numpy import *

roll = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
roll = array(roll).T

notes, frames = roll.shape
pm = PrettyMIDI()
instr = Instrument(program = 80)
roll = pad(roll, [(0, 0), (1, 1)], 'constant')
velocity_changes = nonzero(np.diff(roll).T)
prev_velocities = zeros(notes, dtype=int)
note_on_time = zeros(notes)
for time, note in zip(*velocity_changes):
    velocity = roll[note, time + 1]
    if velocity > 0:
        if prev_velocities[note] == 0:
            note_on_time[note] = time
            prev_velocities[note] = velocity
    else:
        start_time = note_on_time[note]
        pm_note = Note(
            velocity = 120,
            pitch = note + 40,
            start = start_time,
            end=time)
        instr.notes.append(pm_note)
        for i in range(20):
            time = start_time + i / 20
            bend = PitchBend(400 * i, time)
            instr.pitch_bends.append(bend)
        prev_velocities[note] = 0
pm.instruments.append(instr)
pm.write('test.mid')
```

Comment: thank you very much for answer but I don't understand the values ​​you gave to the code, you can explain more please . i want to use from this cod for generate music What should I do if I just want pitch_bend on the note (c) to change and the rest pitch_bend notes  to be zero?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The basic idea is that you append the `Note` object as normal to the instrument's note sequence but then you also add one or more `PitchBend` objects to its pitch bend sequence. If you only want C notes bent, you have to ensure that using an if-statement.

Comment: Hi ,may you explain your code ,parts get values for example time,bend,pitch,velocity  .Why did you give these values?

Comment: Velocity controls the loudness of the note. Pitch it's frequency index and time its temporal location. The argument to PitchBend the amount of bending at that point in time. Refer to the [MIDI specification](https://docs.isy.liu.se/pub/VanHeden/DataSheets/The_MIDI_Specification.pdf) for details.

Comment: I used from your code with a  bit changes for value pitchbend on note (B) but generated music not good .Which part of the code needs to be changed??

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import glob
import random
from pretty_midi import* 
import IPython
import numpy as np
#from tqdm import tnrange, tqdm_notebook, tqdm
from random import shuffle, seed
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import choice
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook,tnrange, tqdm_notebook, tqdm
import unicodedata
import re
import numpy as np
import os
import io
import time
from numpy import *
#stragglers = {}
#channel==0
piano_roll = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
piano_roll = array(piano_roll).T
note_name=['A5','B5','C5','D5','E5','F5','G5']
def piano_roll_to_pretty_midi(piano_roll, fs=100, program=80):
notes, frames = piano_roll.shape
pm = pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI()
instrument = pretty_midi.Instrument(program=program)


#semitone_range=2.
#for pitch_bend in range (len(utilities.semitones_to_pitch_bend(semitones,                                                                                                                                        semitone_range=2.))):
#tone=[-8192,8192]
#quarter_tone==tone%4
notes, frames = piano_roll.shape
pm = PrettyMIDI()
#instr = Instrument(program = 80)
piano_roll = pad(piano_roll, [(0, 0), (1, 1)], 'constant')
velocity_changes = nonzero(np.diff(piano_roll).T)
prev_velocities = zeros(notes, dtype=int)
note_on_time = zeros(notes)
for time, note in zip(*velocity_changes):
    velocity = piano_roll[note, time + 1]
    if velocity > 0:
        if prev_velocities[note] == 0:
            note_on_time[note] = time
            prev_velocities[note] = velocity
    else:
        start_time = note_on_time[note]
        pm_note = Note(
            velocity = 10,
            pitch = note +10,
            start = start_time,
            end=time)
        instrument.notes.append(pm_note)
        for i in range(20):
            if note_name=='B5':
                time = start_time + i / 20
                bend = PitchBend(102 * i, time)
                instrument.pitch_bends.append(bend)
            prev_velocities[note] = 0
pm.instruments.append(instrument)
return pm
```